Some Tailwind classes are not applied
I'm using Tailwind in a Vue3 project and I'm encountering weird behavior with some classes. For examle, I have this code :
<li class="border-solid border-l border-red-500"> 

In VScode, when I hover the border-l property, it displays this :

But in my browser dev tools, the class simply does not exist on this tag (the class is present in the DOM but does not have any style linked to it)

I checked my tailwind.config.ts file and everything looks great in it (and I think the problem can't come from this file, as other classes works, for example border-red-500 is visible and is working)

Consider checking the code is covered by the content file globs in the Tailwind configuration.

Please provide tailwind.config.ts and the file path to the element in question.

content: ["./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"]
and the path is  /src/components/myComp.vue

as I said, border-red-500 is applied so the file IS covered by content. This only happens with some classes like border-l for example

Are some class labels dynamically compiled ? If yes, they will not be in the build of tailwind css. Use full names or list the classes that should be enforced in the tailwind config

dynamically compled is for custom values ? like when you want to choose a custom number of px ? Becase that's not my case. I'm using the standard class bordel-l, which should be available without adding it in the config, no ?

Run:
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./src/style/index.css

